# Apache sentry - Get sentry groups to which a given database/tables has been assigned to

Tags: cloudera, apache-sentry

I want get for a given database/table the list of groups this database/table has been granted access in sentry.

Comment: Even If I can get a Java REST api to connect to Sentry service might do a job for me.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be a Sentry SHOW command for this purpose in the [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/sg_hive_sql.html).

This [blog post](https://vijayjt.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/how-to-determine-sentry-group-to-role.html) suggests that you can instead query the Sentry database directly (assuming you are using the Sentry service, not policy files).

> However, at present there is no command to show the group to role
>   mapping. The only way to do this is by connecting to the Sentry
>   database and deriving this information from the tables in the
>   database.
>
> If you're using CDH you can determine which node in the cluster is
>   running the Sentry database using Cloudera Manager, navigating to
>   Clusters >  Sentry, then clicking Sentry Server and then
>   Configuration. Here you will find the type of database being used
>   (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle), the server the databases is running
>   on, it's port, the database name and user.

You will need the Sentry database password - the blog post gives a suggestion for retrieving it if you do not know it.

An example query for a PostgreSQL database is given:

```
SELECT "SENTRY_ROLE"."ROLE_NAME","SENTRY_GROUP"."GROUP_NAME"
FROM "SENTRY_ROLE_GROUP_MAP"
JOIN "SENTRY_ROLE" ON "SENTRY_ROLE"."ROLE_ID"="SENTRY_ROLE_GROUP_MAP"."ROLE_ID"
JOIN "SENTRY_GROUP" ON "SENTRY_GROUP"."GROUP_ID"="SENTRY_ROLE_GROUP_MAP"."GROUP_ID";
```

However, I have not tried this query myself.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for MySQL:

```
SELECT R.ROLE_NAME, G.GROUP_NAME
FROM SENTRY_ROLE_GROUP_MAP RGM
JOIN SENTRY_ROLE R ON R.ROLE_ID=RGM.ROLE_ID
JOIN SENTRY_GROUP G ON G.GROUP_ID=RGM.GROUP_ID;
```